# Tapestry5 compiling error returning service interface in service locator method

Tags: java, spring, tapestry

I have a service locator class called DMSServiceLocator.class, I have a method within it called getParser() with a return type called Parser.  I'm trying to return a service called AutoMateParser with an Impl that extends Parser, however I'm getting a compiling error saying Parser is required, found AutoMateParser. When I return new AutoMateServiceImpl() rather than my service interface, I receive no compiling errors. It doesn't appear my getParser() method realizes autoMateParser is of the same type. I tried casting AutoMateParser with Parser, "return (Parser) autoMateParser;" which resolved compiling errors, but received a cast exception. I'm wondering if anybody knows how to do this. Thanks in advance.

below is a sample of my code.

AppModule.class

```
public static void bind(ServiceBinder binder) {
        binder.bind(AutoMateParser.class, AutoMateParserImpl.class);
}
```

DMSServiceLocator.class

```
public class DMSServiceLocator {

    @Inject
    private AutoMateParser autoMateParser;

    public Parser getParser() {
        if(automate) {
        return autoMateParser();
        } else {
           //Different data scrubber, but also extends Parser
           return homenetParser();
        }
    }

}
```

AutoMateParserImpl.class

```
public class AutoMateParserImpl extends Parser implements AutoMateParser {
    protected Vehicle parseCar(String vehicleData) {
        //some data scrubbing code
    }
}
```

Parser.class

```
public abstract class Parser {
    //some csv line reader code
    protected abstract Vehicle parseCar(String carData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return an object of type `AutoMateParser`. That interface is not a sub-type of `Parser` (only `AutoMateParserImpl` is), hence the compiler complains. You'll need to re-think your class hierarchy.

You could extract a `Parser` interface with the `parseCar` method, have `AutoMateParser` extend that interface, create an abstract `ParserImpl` class implementing the `Parser` interface, and have your service locator return the `Parser` interface type instead of the abstract implementation.

*Edit:* The types could look something like this:

```
public interface Parser {
   //public methods that you need to call
}

public interface AutoMateParser extends Parser {
    //any extra or overriden method declarations
}

public abstract class AbstractParser implements Parser {
    //common code and implemented methods
    protected abstract Vehicle parseCar(String carData);
}

public class AutoMateParserImpl extends AbstractParser implements AutoMateParser {
    //any extra or overriden method implementations defined in AutoMateParser
    protected Vehicle parseCar(String vehicleData) {
        ...
    }
}

public class DMSServiceLocator {

    @Inject
    private AutoMateParser autoMateParser;
    //more services

    public Parser getParser() {
        if(automate) {
           return autoMateParser();
        } else {
           //Different data scrubber, but also extends Parser
           return homenetParser();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I seem to be really confused with your suggested solution though. Would you be able to provide an example? Also, would I still be able to return different services that all extend the Parser interface? Thanks

Comment: @George, I created an example. Yes, returning different subclasses of `Parser` does work if the type hierarchy is corrented like this.

Comment: I've implemented your example and removed all methods except for those in the example and still seem to get the following compiling error incompatible types
  required: com.company.community.task.imports.impl.AbstractParser
  found:    com.company.community.task.imports.automate.AutoMateParser 

Do you have any thoughts? Thanks Henning.

Comment: I made a little java app outside of tapestry and your suggestion seemed to work perfect. Apparently I must be doing something wrong in my tap app, so I'll have to figure that out tonight. Anyhow, thank you once again for all your help. I learned a little something new about java today.